# docker build is not able to connect to http server even though it is accessible on the command line

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core-2.0, nuget-server

We have a `Dockerfile` that contains a command of the form

```
RUN dotnet restore --no-cache -s http://localhost:8081/repository/nuget-hosted/
```

When we run

```
docker build .
```

The error encountered at this line is

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://localhost:8081/repository/nuget-repo-name/FindPackagesById()?id='Package.Name''.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    Couldn't connect to server
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.101/NuGet.targets(104,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'Package.Name' from remote source 'http://localhost:8081/repository/nuget-repo-name/FindPackagesById()?id='Package.Name''.
```

However, when we run this same command on the command line, the `dotnet restore` is successful.

The nuget server in question is running on the same machine. If we hit the same URL in the browser, it is a success.

How do we make the nuget server running at localhoat:8081 accessible within `docker build` so that the docker image gets created successfully?

Comment: `localhost` on your host is not the same as `localhost` in your container.

Comment: I would recommend you to run with docker network ip-address of the host rather then providing 'localhost'; because in your case docker looks for localhost running inside the container thus if you provide the docker network ip-address of the host then it will try to reach the host machine. I hope this would help you to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080064/tkausl replacing http://localhost:8081/repository/nuget-hosted/ with http://1.2.3.4:8081/repository/nuget-hosted/ where 1.2.3.4 is the actual ip address solved the issue.